# Inserting multiple checkbox selection into Mysql using nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am having issues inserting more than one selection into mysql.  I am able to select one value only and it will be inserted into the 'Weekend' table, but when I select more than one day then it errors out.  I am not sure how to put the inputs into an array and insert it into mysql.  Any guidance will be appreciated, thank you!
passport.js

```
var LocalStrategy = require("passport-local").Strategy;
var mysql = require('mysql');
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');
var dbconfig = require('./database');
var connection = mysql.createConnection(dbconfig.connection);
connection.query('USE ' + dbconfig.database);
module.exports = function(passport) {
 passport.serializeUser(function(user, done){
  done(null, user.id);
 });

 passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done){
  connection.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ? ", [id],
   function(err, rows){
    done(err, rows[0]);
   });
 });

 passport.use(
  'local-signup',
  new LocalStrategy({
   firstNameField: 'firstName', 
   lastNameField: 'lastName',
   passReqToCallback: true
  },
  function(req, firstName, lastName, done){ 
    var Weekdays = req.body.Weekdays;

    var newUserMysql = {
          firstName: firstName,
          lastName: lastName,
          Weekdays: Weekdays,

         };

         var insertQuery = "INSERT INTO users (firstName, lastName, Weekdays) values (?, ?, ?)";

         connection.query(insertQuery, [newUserMysql.firstName,newUserMysql.TXDotContact, newUserMysql.lastName,newUserMysql.Weekdays],
          function(err, rows){
           newUserMysql.id = rows.insertId;

           return done(null, newUserMysql);
          });

  })
 );


};
```

signup.js

```
<div class="form-group">
      <label>Weekday(s):
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox" name="Weekdays[]" value="Sunday" /> Sunday<br />
          <input type="checkbox" name="Weekdays[]" value="Monday" /> Monday<br />
          <input type="checkbox" name="Weekdays[]" value="Tuesday" /> Tuesday<br />
          <input type="checkbox" name="Weekdays[]" value="Wednesday" /> Wednesday<br />
          <input type="checkbox" name="Weekdays[]" value="Thursday" /> Thursday<br />
          <input type="checkbox" name="Weekdays[]" value="Friday" /> Friday<br />
          <input type="checkbox" name="Weekdays[]" value="Saturday" /> Saturday<br />
        </div><br />
      </label>
    </div>
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to replace var Weekdays = req.body.Weekdays; with the following below.  The selections were being picked up by the console, but I was not able to insert an array into the table.  I had to format it using JSON.stringify.

```
for (var Weekdays in req.body.Weekdays) {
      if (req.body.Weekdays) {
        items = req.body.Weekdays;
        Weekdays = JSON.stringify(items).replace(/]|[[]|"/g, '',)
        // console.log(items);
      }
    }
```